# Get arrays data by keys using recursive function

Tags: php

Function getting an array(s) to loop though to get all child categories of selected category. Array look something like:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [id] => 7 
        [title] => Deserts 
        [slug] => deserts 
        [child] => Array ( 
            [0] => Array ( 
                [id] => 8 
                [title] => Space 
                [slug] => space 
                [child] => Array ( 
                    [0] => Array ( 
                        [id] => 
                        [title] => 
                        [slug] => 
                        [child] => Array ( ) 
                    ) 
                ) 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
)
```

I come up with a code to display all the values with `foreach()` loop, but I can't make things work when I need data from an exact key, for example `$category['id']`

```
public static function recursiveChildCategory($categories = [], $depth = 0) {

        // Loop through categories
        foreach($categories as $category){

        // If $category is an array.
        if(is_array($category)){

            // Drop empty arrays
            $filteredCategory = array_filter($category);

            // Loop
            self::recursiveChildCategory($filteredCategory, $depth + 1);
        } else {
            //It is not an array, so print it out
       echo str_repeat("&nbsp;&nbsp;", $depth), $category, '<br>';

        }
    }
}
```

currently variable `$category` just prints outs all values. I want to get all info separately, like `$category['id']`, `$category['title']` and etc.

Thanks in advice

Comment: so what's the problem? use `$category['id']` instead of `$category`

Comment: @MateiMihai I think that wont help, `$category` could already be the id or title etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just test of the fieldname value, see

```php
    public static function recursiveChildCategory($categories = [], $depth = 0) {
            // Loop through categories
            foreach($categories as $category){

            // If $category is an array.
            if(is_array($category)){

                // Drop empty arrays
                $filteredCategory = array_filter($category);

                // Loop
                self::recursiveChildCategory($filteredCategory, $depth + 1);
            } else {
                //It is not an array, so print it out
                if($fieldOrIndex === 'id') {
                   echo str_repeat("&nbsp;&nbsp;", $depth), $category, '<br>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

To get separated tree prints for every field in category I think you have to call the function for every field. Replacing the "id"-string with function arg and call it with "id", "title" etc.

EDIT: to have all category data for e.g. creating a link:

```php
public static function recursiveChildCategory($categories = [], $depth = 0) {
    // Loop through categories
    foreach($categories as $category){
        echo str_repeat("&nbsp;&nbsp;", $depth);
        echo "<a href='foo_bar_{$category['id']}'>{$category['title']}</a>";
        echo '<br>';

        if(isset($category['child'])){
            // Loop
            self::recursiveChildCategory($category['child'], $depth + 1);
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input it indeed works, but how I could wrap it into markup, to echo a link to category for example?

Comment: just add an html link `echo str_repeat("&nbsp;&nbsp;", $depth), "<a href='{$URL}'>{$category}</a>", '<br>';` of course you need to create the link url.

Comment: The thing is, I need separate key values just as I described to generate link to child category, so its vital here

Comment: so you need all data of a category to generate the link?

Comment: I updated my post adding a version providing all category data. Please see if it works for you

Comment: Thanks a bunch, works like charm! Broke my mind to achieve this, kinda new to this stuff. Btw, wanted to ask is it possible to use a return of this function to foreach results inside of html with depth? I'm building my micro framework and according to OOP its bad to have markup inside of function, or in this case it really doesn't matter?

Comment: Nice! NP. Yeah its not that nice to create markup that way. But there are many ways to do it. You can echo markup directly, you can return the markup and echo it somewhere else, you can use php as template engine or get a another template engine like twig and prepare your data to fill a template or post data between client and server in json format ... depends on your framework you want to write or what you want to do with your framework. Current version I think is not a good way. In my opinion you should distinguish between view and data handling / preparation.

Comment: I kinda lost, but maybe you can help me how to make multiple return of this function? I trying to fill an array to loop though it in view to get values, but currently it just returns first depth of categories and no more, as function cant return multiple times

Comment: Mh, I think you can open a new question for that problem, so you can also post your code that´s not working as expected.